# How can I see all the reviews done today in any queue?

Tags: support, review, statistics

I've noticed that when you go to the homepage for any review queue ([here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/close/stats) for instance), it shows the top 20 reviewers and how many reviews they've done for the current day.

However, I want to see *all* the reviewers and their number of reviews for today. How can I do this?

Comment: You’ve been asking a lot of Qs on Meta. Beyond the ostensible reasons for each of these Qs... is something else motivating you? Are you trying to earn rep? Are you jonesing for the buzz of a really highly voted Q on Meta? It’s not that you’re doing anything wrong, it just seems like something else is going on here.

Comment: @DanBron I have a very curious mind. That's all.

Comment: @DanBron Heh, I've been asking several questions like this and no one has said a thing...

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog Let’s just say you established your brand a long time ago :)

Comment: There's also a lot of stuff I think should be added/changed on SE...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's available only for users with the [Access To Moderator Tools](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) privilege i.e. 10k rep on grduated sites.

Users with this privilege will see full history of the reviews when visiting the [history tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/close/history) of the review queue. (Without the privilege, you'll see only your own reviews there.)

Without enough rep I'm afraid there's no way to see a full review list. If you want to check a specific reviewer, the list of their reviews is available in [their profile > all actions > review](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/140890/martijn-pieters?tab=activity&sort=reviews).

Answer (score 2):

The full review history is only available to users with the moderator tools privilege (10k+ users on designed sites).

If you don't have enough rep to see the full review history, though, you still have enough information to deduce the last few recent reviews.

On the review homepage (`/review`), all users can see the last six users who reviewed tasks in each queue, as well as the amount of time since they last reviewed a task. Clicking on any avatar will direct you to that user's profile, after which you can use Shadow's method in the other answer to see reviews cast by that user.

Note that reviews in the Low Quality Posts review queue aren't in the public list; this is to prevent onlookers from getting an incorrect perspective of one's review history (since reviews on deleted posts aren't shown there).